# nested click events causing the inside function to repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the user to click once and then I will use some CSS to highlight the character they chose and then they will click the same Chinese character again to hear the character tone sounded out.

To duplicate it, go to this site:
http://shawnwow.com/chineseCharacterHelpr/

I am on chrome (not sure if that matters) and if you type "mao" or anything really, and click on the same character a few times you will see the first time it does what it supposed to (plays 0 times), as does the second time (plays 1 time), but then I click a third time in a row and then it plays the audio 2 times and then 3 times, and then 4 times, and so on.

I assume it has something to do with the fact I have nested clicks (which is bad, as I have read), but I would like that functionality but don't know what else to do. Maybe I can have the second .click be a hover but then I wouldn't know what to do for mobile devices.

Here is the code directly; it starts on line 32:

https://github.com/olmansju/chineseCharacterHelpr/blob/master/JS/scripts.js

Comment: Yes it's bad to generally nest event handlers, there isn't a reason to do so. That code keeps binding more and more click event handlers for the same element as you call `.click`, that's why it's happening.

Comment: Gotcha, I think I'll go a different route then, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be summed up in pseudo-code as follows

```
if click on list item then
  attach another click handler on list item
```

So, on multiple clicks, multiple click handlers are being attached. The pseudo-code which will solve your problem is as follows

```
if click on list item then
  detach any existing click handler
  attach another click handler on list item
```

Here is some code to implement this

```
var clickHandler = function () {
  console.log(selectedCharacter);
  responsiveVoice.speak(selectedCharacter, 'Chinese Female');
}
$(this).off("click", clickHandler);
$(this).on("click", clickHandler);
```

This will solve your problem, but it's not the best way to be working with event handlers. Maybe, you should create radio buttons for the entire list and provide a button which would play the sound of the selected character.

Comment: Thanks! I think I am going another route but if my boss insists on this way I will do that!